# Hibernate mapping ManyToOne with many parents

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have such mappings:

```
<!-- language: java --> 
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
class CommonResource {
  // mapping to all parents here   
}

class CommonResourceChild extends CommonResource { }

class Parent1 {  
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "parent1_common_resource_type1", 
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "parent1_id")}, 
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "common_resource_id")})
  List<CommonResource> commonResourcesType1;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "parent1_common_resource_type2", 
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "parent1_id")}, 
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "common_resource_id")})
  List<CommonResource> commonResourcesType2;
}

class Parent2 { //almost the same mapping, but with another parent
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "parent2_common_resource_type1", 
       joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "parent2_id")}, 
       inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "common_resource_id")})
  List<CommonResource> commonResourcesType1;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "parent2_common_resource_type2", 
       joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "parent2_id")}, 
       inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "common_resource_id")})
  List<CommonResource> commonResourcesType2;
}

@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
abstract class AbstractParent3 { } // not every Parent3 have CommonResource

class Parent3Impl extends AbstractParent3 {      
    // some Parent2 can have CommonResource or it's children
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
  CommonResourceChild commonResourceChild;
}
```

Is it possible to somehow map every CommonResource entity and its subtypes to different parents according to the following points?

1. Some of parents have lists of CommonResources or its children,
2. Some of parents (or theirs children) have one instance of CommonResources or its children,

I'm free to change mappings or modify DB, because I haven't released it yet. :)